# Magento - Change customer tax class id dynamically to affect existing order

Tags: magento

Is it possible to dynamically update the customer_tax_class_id attribute of an oder being processed - for guest customers.

I have tried setting it via the checkout/session model but it will not update.

The goal is to reset the tax amount based upon a condition to 0.  Using the tax_class_id which will have a rule of 0 tax.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this before the order is submitted, so that the user pays the correct amount the first time (and has no surprises). Is there a reason that you cannot determine the tax_class in advance?

Comment: I am also interested in this. I had a situation recently where I am validating vat numbers at the checkout process. If a valid vat number is found then tax/vat is to be taken off. I have tried several different approaches all unsuccessfully. What would you suggest here @joseph.

Comment: I'm also trying to achieve this. My goal is to make the customer able to switch between two customer classes, normal and company, where company has a VAT number and vat-rates of zero. This way you wouldn't have to apply vat rules somewhere in the checkout.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am aiming for.  I want to be able to switch the VAT to 0 during the checkout process based a valid vat number being entered. I have exhuasted every possible avenue.  Would be very impressed if someone could solve this.

Comment: This was from six years ago, so it's all lost to the mists of time. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯​